# Javascript action in object when id is in another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a problem with my code in Google maps API v3. Markers are updating every minute (or manually at any time). But I do not want to erase all markers and then again "re-upload" cause markers then "blinking".

I have many filters in our website that affect the viewing markers. So one time there may be 5000 markers and after 1 sec should be just a 1.

But how can I do it correctly? There is mine "addMarker" function.

```
this.addMarker = function(id, object)
    {
        if(typeof object == 'undefined'){
            return;
        }

        if(!this.markers[id])
        {
            object.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(object.lat, object.lng),
                icon: object.image
            });
            if((object.approved == "1" && MapApprovedControl.enabled) || object.approved == "0" && MapUnapprovedControl.enabled){
                object.marker.setMap(this.canvas);
            }

            this.markers[id] = object;
        }
        else
        {
            if(this.markers[id].marker.getIcon() != object.image) {
                this.markers[id].markers.setIcon(object.image);
            }

            if(this.markers[id].marker.getMap() == null){
                this.markers[id].marker.setMap(this.canvas);
            }
        }

        this.updated.push(id);
    };
```

In "else" block i'm adding the index into array, so I can find out which data are already there and which markers missing.

```
    this.updated = [];

    this.update = function()
    {
        if(this.updated.length > 0)
        {
            $.each(this.markers, function(index)
            {
                var exists = false;
                $.each(map.updated, function(key, value){
                    if(index == value){
                        exists = true;
                        return;
                    }
                });

                if(!exists){
                    map.markers[index].marker.setMap(null);
                }
            });

            this.updated = [];
        }
    };
```

and when map are updated this happening:

```
$.getScript('/Of1dPGvNutBUMJdfGSmJKeZwWjR4MGmUVoBDhb9I/pTTegD9WefgHfx7WzNhP', function() {
                map.update();
            });
```

In this URL is just "addMarker(..); addMarker(...);"

But this solution are not correct. Once it works, once nope - not sure why :D + it's slow.

So my questions is :

1. How to update markers correctly?
2. During the update, do I have two cycles, is there any way to use array filter?

Thanks a lot!

EDIT: I modified the code, deleted uselessness and moved "this.updated.push (id)" after conditions. This solved the problem with the fact that sometimes it worked and sometimes did not. Still, it remains a problem with two cycles. (I still think that this is not the right way)

EDIT1: OK, still does not working sometimes... Usually when I get a smaller number of markers than I had previously.

EDIT2: OK, the script (ajax snippet) is not loaded sometimes (probably cached, idk)

EDIT3: This is probably the best way to update markers without 2 cycles

```
this.update = function()
{
    if(this.updated.length > 0)
    {
        $.each(map.markers, function(index){
            if($.inArray(index, map.updated) == -1){
                map.markers[index].marker.setMap(null);
            }
        });
        this.updated = [];
    }
};
```

But I still don't know how to load mine JS file (if there is a lot of markers, so the script just does not read, does not write any error) - pfff I don't get it.

EDIT4: Ok, it's probably fixed by adding this (in ajax snippet - update)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function load_js()
        {
            var head= document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
            var script= document.createElement('script');
            script.type= 'text/javascript';
            script.src= '/Of1dPGvNutBUMJdfGSmJKeZwWjR4MGmUVoBDhb9I/pTTegD9WefgHfx7WzNhP';
            head.appendChild(script);
        }
        load_js();
    </script>
```

and also adding "map.update();" line after last line in /Of1dPGvNutBUMJdfGSmJKeZwWjR4MGmUVoBDhb9I/pTTegD9WefgHfx7WzNhP file.

Next problem is: load just markers when they does not exists in our map (hey this topic is like private notepad, lel)

Ok, its probably "unsolvable" and I need power of god, to be continued...
BUT THANKS A LOT FOR HELP ANYWAY! :-))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you thought about hiding markers instead of redisplaying them for every filter? Display all of the markers, and then turn off all of the ones not in the filter set. That keeps your code clean because you only have to output the markers once.